# Associations not working in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have the following Tables

> Articles
>
> ---
>
> **Id**  title  description  image author published created
>
> Comments
>
> ---
>
> **Id**  **user_id**  **article_id**  text created
>
> Users
>
> ---
>
> **Id** login name email pass

I want that **Article** relates with **Comments** and **Comments** relates with **Users**, but i can not. Yet I have the following models.

**Article**

```
<?php

/**
* Model de artigos
*/
class Article extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'Article';

    public $hasMany = array(
                            'Comment' => array(
                                                'className' => 'Comment',
                                                'dependent' => false,
                                                'fields' => array('Comment.user_id','Comment.created','Comment.text'),
                                                'foreignkey' => 'article_id',

                                                )
                            );

    /**
    * Regras de validação
    *
    * @var array
    */
    public $validate = array();

    /**
    * Lista dos artigos mais recentes
    *
    * @param int $limit Quantidade de artigos
    * @param array $params Parâmetros extras de busca
    *
    * @return array
    */
    public function recent($limit = 5, $params = array()) {
        $params = Hash::merge(array(
        'conditions' => array('Article.published' => true),
        'order' => array('Article.created' => 'DESC'),
        'limit' => $limit
        ), $params);

        return $this->find('all', $params);
    }

}
```

**Comment**

```
<?php

/**
* Model de comentários
*/
class Comment extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'Comment';

    public $belongsTo = array(
                            'User' => array(
                                            'className' => 'User',
                                            'foreignKey'   => 'user_id',
                                            'type'  => 'left'
                                            )
                             );

    /**
    * Regras de validação
    *
    * @var array
    */
    public $validate = array();

    /**
    * Lista dos comentários mais recentes
    *
    * @param int $limit Quantidade de comentários
    * @param array $params Parâmetros extras de busca
    *
    * @return array
    */
    public function recent($limit = 5, $params = array()) {
        $params = Hash::merge(array(
            'conditions' => array('Comment.published' => true),
            'order' => array('Comment.created' => 'DESC'),
            'limit' => $limit
        ), $params);

        return $this->find('all', $params);
    }

}
```

**User**

```
/**
* Model de usuários
*/
class User extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'User';

    /**
    * Regras de validação
    *
    * @var array
    */
    public $validate = array();

}
```

I only can relates **Articles** with **Comments**, but I can not **Comments** with **Users**. What I need do? Thanks for helping.

Comment: If you want from `recent()` method in `Article` model, to query articles, comments and users you should set the `recursive` attribute to `2` in your `$params` array. Check out [Recursive](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive) in the CakePHP docs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `$hasMany` to user model.

```
/**
* Model de usuários
*/
class User extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'User';
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Comment' => array(
            'className' => 'Comment',
            'dependent' => false,
            'fields' => array('Comment.user_id','Comment.created','Comment.text'),
            'foreignkey' => 'user_id',
        )
    );
    /**
    * Regras de validação
    *
    * @var array
    */
    public $validate = array();

}
```